# Flow NULL value checking not working

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow which set some variables to fields that may be unassigned on the record. However, the formula does first do a check to see if the field is NULL or blank. Even with this check the flow fails with the error

> The flow failed to access the value for
> GetObjectData.Object_UserLookup__c because it hasn't been set or
> assigned.

Am I doing my check wrong? Prior to the assignment node (where the flow fails) there is a check to see if the GetObjectData var is NULL too, and it wont reach the assignment node if it were NULL.

Here's what the assignments look like:

UserLookupIfPresent - Forumla

```
IF(AND(NOT(ISNULL({!GetObjectData.Object_UserLookup__c })),NOT(ISBLANK({!GetObjectData.Object_UserLookup__c }))),{!GetObjectData.Object_UserLookup__c },'')
```

`UserLookup` - Variable
Default Value :  `{!UserLookupIfPresent}`

Assign Record Values:

`{!$Record.UserLookup__c}` Equals `{!UserLookup}`

Assigning a value to the field on the record does stop the error, but the field may need to be blank in some cases.

Comment: Assuming `GetObjectData` is a Get element, can you share the configuration you've set for that Get. Or share how it is your are populating `GetObjectData`

Comment: GetObjectData is actually a custom invocable method written so that I can query an object using multi-select picklist INCLUDES function as its not provided but the Get Records node. It returns the object matching the criteria specified. It does find the object correctly (the debug flow interview/path has a valid ID returned) and the next node is also a null check on the GetObjectData response.